# phpMyAdmin error 403

Tags: wordpress, apache, phpmyadmin, localhost, virtualhost

I installed phpMyAdmin over a year ago.
Then I installed WordPress few month ago.

At that moment, I followed [this tutorial](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/set-virtual-hosts-apache-mac-osx-10-9-mavericks-osx-10-8-mountain-lion/) to add virtual host:

Now when I try to access phpMyAdmin with that URL, http://localhost/phpmyadmin/, I have:

> 403 Forbiden error
>   You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server.

in /etc/apache2/users/myuser.conf:

```
<Directory "/Users/myuser/Sites/">
AllowOverride All
Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
Require all granted

</Directory>

Include /Users/myuser/Sites/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Then in my httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<Directory "/Users/myuser/Sites">
AllowOverride All
Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost _default_:80>
 ServerName localhost
 DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents
 </VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName site1.local
 DocumentRoot "/Users/myuser/Sites/site1"
</VirtualHost>
```

So I can't access to phpMyAdmin and localhost/Sites/site1 which I suppose was my URL to access my WordPress website locally.

The answer is [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/85592/phpmyadmin-error-403-no-matching-directoryindex-index-html-found-and-server/85625?noredirect=1#comment104311_85625)

Comment: Try here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: i'm gonna try that. thanks.